# How to define a table with fixed width but auto column widths at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I want a table with a fixed width (i.e. 300px) with 3 columns where the first and the last have the minimum width determined by its contents, and the middle one extends to cover the remaining space.

With an auto table layout, the table width is ignored:

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.min-width {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="min-width">1</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
    </td>
    <td class="min-width">One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="min-width">2</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
      Nulla vitae rhoncus enim quis rhoncus ex
    </td>
    <td class="min-width">Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="min-width">3</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
      Aenean eu tincidunt purus morbi fringilla eu elit non ultrices
    </td>
    <td class="min-width">Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With a fixed table layout, the table width is respected, but the minimum width for the columns is ignored (it's the same HTML):

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.min-width {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="min-width">1</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
    </td>
    <td class="min-width">One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="min-width">2</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
      Nulla vitae rhoncus enim quis rhoncus ex
    </td>
    <td class="min-width">Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="min-width">3</td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
      Aenean eu tincidunt purus morbi fringilla eu elit non ultrices
    </td>
    <td class="min-width">Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is possible to fix the table width and at the same time define some columns with a minimum width and expand the remaining?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used !important in css before to override styling rules for a specific property.

Format it like this

```
table {
    width: 300px; !important
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

you can try it with your css to see if it works